# Apps script onFormSubmit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have the following code at the end of a Google Form. The first value in the form is a string that I am trying to use as the name of a file that will be created. Just trying to test things out while submitting fake forms myself . I know that the trigger itself is working based on my first line of code (commented out for now) working. I am trying to troubleshoot what is wrong.

```
    Function onFormSubmit(e) {
     // this line works var NewSpreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.Create("testing");
     var AnswerObject = e.namedValues;
     var DirectoryName = AnswerObject[0][0]; //toString() necessary??
     if (DirectoryName) {
     var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Empty");
    ssNew.getRange('A1').setValue(DirectoryName);
    }
```

Edit: If I try `AnswerObject['Directory'][0]` the same thing happens.

The code is not responding to the `if` statement, and after some other tests of placing lines of code I know will work it seems that something is going wrong with my `e.namedValues` object. Any help troubleshooting would be great.

Comment: The screen on which you create a trigger offers email notification of failure. Set it to "immediate". The email will have a line on which the error occurs, and the error message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the variable AnswerObject is as you named it an **object** you won't access an object content with an index but with a name.
you need to set DirectoryName with the name of the question you are interested in.
eg: one of my form question is "name of the directory" so I'll set directoryName like that: `var DirectoryName = AnswerObject["name of the directory"]`
You should also use `Logger.log()` to check what's happening it will save you time, it's more efficient than writing something in a spreadsheet
One last thing in JS variables start with a lower case, it wont break your code but it's a convention (same for 'function')

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var AnswerObject = e.namedValues;
  Logger.log(AnswerObject);
  var directoryName = AnswerObject[0];
  Logger.log(directoryName); // this is undefined as there is nothing at the index 0
  //var DirectoryName = AnswerObject[0][0]; //toString() necessary??
  if (directoryName) {
    Logger.log("in it"); // never triggered
    var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Empty");
    ssNew.getRange('A1').setValue(directoryName);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't test "e" values without submitting a real form, so logging the values in the console doesn't work. I also mentioned in the original post that I tried both object methods.